# ASP.NET 4.0 - Using Jquery, how do I call a codebehind function and return data to the client?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

When I click on the following div:

```
 <div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>
```

I need the following codebehind function to run:

```
 <WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function GetDate() As String
     Return DateTime.Now.ToString()
 End Function
```

I need this to populate the inside of the div with the string returned by the GetDate() function. I think this should use code similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
        $("#Result").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.aspx/GetDate",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                    $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've pulled this example from this site: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

However, I simply cannot get it to work. Nothing happens. This is just a regular asp.net web project. I haven't done any sort of Ajax-enabling business other than including script tags in my markup to reference jquery.

Here's what the firebug console tells me when I click on the div:

```
 POST http://admin/Default.aspx   GetDate   404 Not Found   -18ms
```

Edit: Note: test.aspx/GetDate must match your aspx page name and function name!

Comment: Make your server-side function static

Comment: Where did you put GetDate function? Your code call it at admin/Default.aspx, so the code must be in Default.aspx.vb. It must be static as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetDate() As String
    Return DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function
```

Gotta be "Shared" ("static" in C#)